# Tensorflow 2.8 Saved model convert to TF-TRT

Tags: tensorflow, inference, tensorrt

How to convert a Tensorflow model with save model format to TF-TRT for online inference?

I searched the manual and some related blogs, it seems that all what said is converting a dense graph. The code snippet is as follows:

```
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
 
MAX_BATCH_SIZE=128
def input_fn():
   batch_size = MAX_BATCH_SIZE
   x = x_test[0:batch_size, :]
   yield [x]

converter = trt.TrtGraphConverterV2(
   input_saved_model_dir=SAVED_MODEL_DIR,
   precision_mode=trt.TrtPrecisionMode.FP32
)
 
trt_func = converter.convert()
 
converter.build(input_fn=input_fn)

OUTPUT_SAVED_MODEL_DIR="./models/tftrt_saved_model"
converter.save(output_saved_model_dir=OUTPUT_SAVED_MODEL_DIR)
```

However my inference model includes embedding layer and dense layers. The code snippet is like:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 50), dtype=tf.int64, name="user_fea1"),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 50), dtype=tf.int64, name="user_fea2"),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 50), dtype=tf.int64, name="user_fea3"),
                              tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.float32)])
def predict(self, input_1, input_2, input_3, item_emb):
    ####  1. embedding layer code #####
    user_feat = [input_1, input_2, input_3]
    mask = (user_feat[0] >= 0)
    item_list = self.item_id_embedding(tf.where(mask, user_feat[0], 0))
    shop_list = self.shop_id_embedding(tf.where(mask, user_feat[1], 0))
    cat1_list = self.cat1_embedding(tf.where(mask, user_feat[2], 0))
    user_emb = tf.concat([item_list, shop_list, cat1_list], -1)

    ####  2. dense layers code #######
    item_emb = tf.expand_dims(item_emb, axis=1)
    att_out = self.nonlinear_attention(item_emb, user_emb, user_emb)
    att_out = tf.reduce_sum(att_out, axis=-2)
    mlp_layer = tf.concat([att_out, item_emb], axis=-1)
    mlp_layer = self.bn1(self.nn_fc1(mlp_layer))
    mlp_layer = tf.nn.selu(mlp_layer)
    mlp_layer = self.bn2(self.nn_fc2(mlp_layer))
    mlp_layer = tf.nn.selu(mlp_layer)
    mlp_layer = self.nn_fc3(mlp_layer)
    logits = tf.nn.sigmoid(mlp_layer)
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 1])

    return logits
```

My question is:

1. How to convert the former model to TR-TRT?
2. As the embedding layer input is tf.int64 format, the can not be used in TF-TRT. If I just want to convert the dense layers to TF-TRT, how should I do with it? please give an example.